# search of a file using command prompt

Tags: search, command-line

In MS Windows XP, in DOS, is it possible to do a content search(for a line or a word) in a file using command prompt.?

If so can we search a directory as well.? i.e it should search all the files in the directory for a specific word or phrase.

Thanks.

Comment: What platform and shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options: `FIND` or `FINDSTR`, both of which are built-in to the Windows Command Prompt.

You can use `FIND` to search for a simple string in a file:

```
FIND "apple" file.txt
```

You can also use it to search all files in the current directory:

```
FIND "apple" *
```

`FINDSTR` has a few more options: you can do searches with regular expressions, and you can search recursively into subdirectories:

```
FINDSTR /s "apple" *
```

In all cases, these commands print each line that matches the string to be searched, along with the file they were found in.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for out of the box solution then you can use the [fndstr](http://www.computerhope.com/findstr.htm) command 
which comes with XP.

Answer (score 0):

[FINDSTR](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

On unix the command is [`find`](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Funixhelp.ed.ac.uk%2FCGI%2Fman-cgi%3Ffind&ei=j5IbTIKUMoT78AbJkIXPCQ&usg=AFQjCNHaviSMBmuFJXPG22_eomJ3V_q8ow), which takes a mini-language on the command line for defining what to find.

The short version of how to use it is:

```
$ find [where in the file tree to start]+ [how to filter files]+ [actions]+
```

and a common usage would be

```
$ find . ~ -name '*.mp3' -print
```

which means start in this directory (`.`) and my home directory (`~`), select only files with names ending in `.mp3` (the `-name` filter), and print the path (using the `-print` action).

There are many more selection operators, and a modest set of actions. To do something complicated with the files you've found you either use `-exec` or print their names and pipe to `xargs`.